# Getting [Object object] when using ng-model on a named form

Tags: forms, angularjs, data-binding

If I have the following:

```
<form
    id="registration"
    name="registration"
    method="POST"
>

    <input
        type="text"
        name="first_name"
        id="first-name"
        ng-model="registration.first_name"
        placeholder="First name"
    />
```

When my form displays, fields configured as above end up having `[Object object]` inside of them for their initial value.

What am I doing wrong here and what's the correct way to get two-way binding inside of a form?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Setting the `name` attribute on a form creates a scope object which is [useful for validation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation) but is not meant to be used for the `ng-model` attributes of inputs.

If you use a separate scope variable for ng-model, it will work as you expect:

```
<form
    ...
    name="reg"
    ...
>

<input
    ...
    ng-model="registration.first_name"
    ...
/>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/EChTU0jU6LtYmoy8HAYF?p=preview)

Comment: Would you happen to know what the preferred method is to obtain the values of a form to perform a submission via an Angular resource?

Answer (score 1):

I guess either the registration scope is not initialized or registration.first_name is an object.

Have a look at this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/bdbs0XVB8hZSodOTYyM4?p=preview

Initialize the registation model either in controller or using ng-init `ng-init="registration = {}"`

If registration.first_name is an object then this will be displayed as `[Object object]`. You have to supply a proper string value as model to the ng-model

Comment: You shouldn't have to init model objects this way. The problem has to do with the fact that `registration` on scope is already being used based on the `<form name="registration">` attribute. Take a look at the demo in my answer to see that this is true.

Answer (score 0):

Angularjs Form showing [object Object] on load in form fields

I am guessing, it will show this error, only if your form name and ng-model name (value) are same

```
like

 <form name="userform">-------
 <input ng-model="userform.firstname">
```

change your **form name or your ng-model** value to user or some xyz

Answer (score 0):

If you don't register a controller in ng-controller, you can remove name="registration" from form, because controller has init with forms, i try and works.

`plnkr.co/edit/JK3utpe1eERrJeoveaCQ?p=preview`