# 'object Object' variable displayed on a form input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

In my AngularJS template I have the following login input field section. It is currently autopopulating the input field with rather than the email address address, it is showing up as in the email field (rather than you@email.com etc..)

```
[object Object]
```

my template/view

```
<input ng-model="form.email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off">
```

The ng-model using the variable form.email (although I cannot see where exactly that is coming from yet) - what could be wrong?

Comment: can we see the model for the form? i presume the `form.email` has other properties and is not just a string.

Comment: looks like you need to call JSON.parse on your form model

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\[\[object Object\]\] appear on textbox in angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29719806/object-object-appear-on-textbox-in-angularjs)

Comment: This one explains it better http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24017294/getting-object-object-when-using-ng-model-on-a-named-form

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting \[Object object\] when using ng-model on a named form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24017294/getting-object-object-when-using-ng-model-on-a-named-form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that `form.email` should be a `string` not an `object`.

**Working demo :**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.form = {
        email: "you@email.com"
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input ng-model="form.email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```